# Do we need the axiom of choice for choosing a sequence out of countably infinite nonempty sets?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm reading a proof of the statement that each closed subset $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as an intersection of a sequence of open subsets. The corresponding sequence is given by $U_n := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \;||x-y||_2 < \frac{1}{n} \text{ for some } y \in F\}$, i.e. one wants to prove that $F = \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_n$. For the direction $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_n \subset F$ the argument is the following: each $x \in \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_n$ is the limit of a sequence of elements in $F$. Since $F$ is closed this implies $x \in F$.

**Question:** Let $x \in \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_n$. It's clear, that every for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we should be able to choose an element $x_n \in F$ such that $||x_n-x||_2 <\frac{1}{n}$ since $U_n$ is not empty (at least when $F$ is not empty). But then we choose infinitely many elements at the same time. Can we somehow justify this or do we need the axiom of choice here?

Comment: Yes, but also no? :p Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument you gave uses the axiom of choice, but an epsilon argument can be given without needing choice. Specifically, consider an arbitrary $x\in\bigcap_nU_n$, and let an arbitrary  $\varepsilon>0$ be given. For any $n>\frac1{\varepsilon}$, the fact that $x\in U_n$ implies that there is some $y\in F$ within distance $\varepsilon$ of $x$. Since $F$ is closed, this means $x\in F$.

More generally, in the absence of countable choice, there can be a severe shortage of sequences. So a statement about sequences can be equivalent, when choice is available, to an epsilon-style statement but no longer equivalent in the absence of choice.